# cakephp upgrade 2.xx to 3.x

Tags: cakephp, upgrade

> Deprecated: PHP configuration files like "app.php" should not set `$config`. Instead return an array. - C:\composer\upgrade\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\Configure.php, line: 343
>   You can disable deprecation warnings by setting `Error.errorLevel` to `E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED` in your config/app.php. in C:\composer\upgrade\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\functions.php on line 311
>   Exception: If config is null, key must be an array. in [C:\composer\upgrade\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\StaticConfigTrait.php, line 79]

I just follow the tools. How to remove the error?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text; post the actual error messages so we can cut and paste. Also, images tend to get compressed on smaller screens, rendering them difficult to read.

Comment: ok.. I'll remove it

Comment: Thank you; I've also tidied up the formatting. Have you tried following the advice there, and if so, what happened? Why didn't it fix the problem? Can you post your `app.php`?

Comment: If your application is big you better stick to the version that you are using. There are many deprecate functions in cake 2. and <3.4 and then you will have and other problem if you want to upgrade from 3.4 to 3.5 and above. Other problem will be upgrading your php version. Cakephp 3.x use php 7.x

Comment: Lots of good reasons to upgrade from 2.x to 3.x. It is lots of work, but can be worth it. And 3.x supports newer versions of PHP than 2.x does, but it also still runs just fine on 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, as the error message indicates, you need to return an array instead of setting `$config`. Change

```
$config = [
```

to

```
return [
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have got this, $ bin/cake upgrade --help
Exception: If config is null, key must be an array.